# Find all valid triplets in this equation

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to find all positive integer triplets a,b,c that satisfy this equation. Note r is a constant.
And 1 does exist: 23,13,121.  Why is the result not found? Is there something wrong with the way I expressed the first expression?

For those with older versions of Mathematica, please replace "PositiveIntegers" with "Integers".

`eqn1 = FullSimplify[{2*r^98 +  14*r^96 + 11*r^94 - r^50 + a*r^46 + b*r^44 + c*r^40 == r^100, r = Sqrt[(Sqrt[53]/2) + 1.5] }]`

Out:
`{2.25039*10^16 a + 4.37815*10^15 b + 1.65712*10^14 c == 0, 2.26717}`

`Table[FindInstance[eqn1, {a, b, c}, PositiveIntegers, 15]]`

Out:
`FindInstance[{2.25039*10^16 a + 4.37815*10^15 b + 1.65712*10^14 c == 0, 2.26717}, {a, b, c}, PositiveIntegers, 15]`

Also: can it be solved outright?

`Solve[{2*r^98 +  14*r^96 + 11*r^94 - r^50 + a*r^46 + b*r^44 + c*r^40 == r^100, r = Sqrt[(Sqrt[53]/2) + 1.5]}, {a, b, c}]`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eqn1 = FullSimplify[
    (2*r^98 + 14*r^96 + 11*r^94 - r^50 + a*r^46 + b*r^44 + c*r^40 == 
        r^100) /. r -> Sqrt[(Sqrt[53]/2) + 3/2]]
```

[image]

```
FindInstance[eqn1, {a, b, c}, Integers, 15] // Column
```

[image]

But, with `PositiveIntegers` as the domain, `FindInstance` can find only one solution:

```
FindInstance[eqn1, {a, b, c}, PositiveIntegers, 15]
```

> ```
> {{a -> 23, b -> 13, c -> 121}}
> ```

Using `Solve`:

```
Solve[eqn1, {a, b, c}, Integers]
```

[image]

```
Solve[eqn1, {a, b, c}, PositiveIntegers]
```

> ```
> {{a -> 23, b -> 13, c -> 121}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks @kglr  Is this the only part you changed? "/. r ->"  Did the original method had a syntax or wrong way to represent?  Also: Why isn't the 23,13,121 showing up in the Integers version?

Comment: I get your first set, but my FindInstance[eqn1, {a, b, c}, PositiveIntegers, 15] returns nothing. neither does the Solve. pasted as-is. Solve says "Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result." ...

Comment: Hi @kglr. See my output! I am not getting even the 15 solutions you have above, they are different. [my output] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l1745GnGH90LtTqqtmjqsnLwwel3OxwW/view).  Why is this? is a setting incorrect on my system?

Comment: @Steve237, I also changed `1.5` to `3/2`.

Comment: See my output Link please above. totally different than what you have shown

Comment: Never mind, I closed down the tool and re-opened fresh and it works. Not sure if it was using references to the previous inputs.